# Connect to wifi using a file

Tags: wifi

My dad has troubles with technology. Is there a way I can send him a file with wifi settings so that he can automatically connect to my network?

Comment: You can always send him a QR code, and he can connect to wifi just by scanning it by using the camera app

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking about him connecting his phone or tabled to your network, you can generate a QR code that when he points his camera at, will prompt him to connect to your network.

Embedded in that QR code is the Wi-Fi name and Password. After the initial connection, his phone or tablet should auto-join.

https://qifi.org/ will allow you to make this QR code which you can then print out.